# Easy way to sub a value in SSRS Lookup if no match?

Tags: reporting-services, lookup

I'm using Lookup in SSRS 2012 to get people's names from one dataset by looking an ID value up in another dataset. A "join" function that allows querying across datasets would be nicer but I'll take what I can get right now. Anyway, I have a number of entries that have nobody assigned to them so they show up as blank since the Lookup returns "Nothing" according to the docs. Is there a simpler way to substitute a value (i.e. "Unassigned") for items that don't match other than something like:

=IIF(IsNothing(long Lookup function),"Unassigned",long Lookup function))

I need to do this in two cells and I have to believe that the Lookup function has to be run twice to satisfy that formula. It already slows down my report a lot, if I double the number of Lookups it will probably double the rendering time. If anyone has a more elegant solution I'd love to see it...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only way I can think of is to use dataset sql query to return values so you don't have to use the Lookups.

Comment: The problem is there are two Data Sources (SQL and Oracle) and two corresponding Datasets, each with its own query. I don't see any way to have a Dataset that can query against two distinct Data Sources....

Comment: Linked server may not be the best option but if it's better than what you have, it might be something to consider [Linked SQL Server with Oracle](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/connecting-sql-server-and-oracle-using-linked-servers)

Comment: Linked server was an initial consideration but I can't modify the Oracle DB in any way so I'm prohibited from having a linked server between the two databases.  I'm seriously considering using SSIS to pull data from Oracle and load it into the SQL DB on a regular basis to simplify the queries and report. I don't need real-time data, hourly would suffice.

Comment: The option to load data to SQL from Oracle is another option which depending on the amount of data may be better than linked server based on your information `not needing real time data`

Comment: Again, I'm not allowed to make any changes to the Oracle DB. It's part of a product bought from a vendor and the app owner doesn't want it modified at all so adding in the data from SQL is not an option. While this discussion would eliminate the need for a Lookup function right now the only option I have is a Lookup function so that brings me back to my original question.

Comment: Even I'm in a similar situation. If somebody has answers or any workaround I would like to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ultimately made a SQL copy of the Oracle DB in our database allowing us to join the two tables and use COALESCE and ISNULL to provide values for missing data.